# Mysql query to find count for different column

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table : **tbl_uesr**

```
admission     discharge        name       unit

2017-05-07    2017-05-10       Deepu      100
2017-05-07    2017-05-09       Nisanth    100
2017-05-08    2017-05-10       Ragesh     100
2017-05-15    2017-05-20       Vidhu      100
2017-05-15    2017-05-21       Reshma     100

2017-05-15    2017-05-21       Sneha      104
2017-06-01    2017-06-10       Lekshmi    104
2017-06-03    2017-06-10       Nidhin     104
2017-06-17    2017-06-20       Vineesh    104

2017-05-07    2017-05-08       Rithun     107
```

The above table describes a particular user's `admission date`, `discharge date` and its `unit`. From the above table I have to find, for a given `date` and `unit` `how many admission happened`, `how many discharge happened`.

For example on **2017-05-07**, there is **2 admission in unit 100**, **1 admission in unit 107**, **no discharge  in any unit**.

So in my result I want all `dates`(admission date and discharge date), `number of admission`, `number of discharge`

**Expected result**

```
Date           no_admission     no_discharge     unit

2017-05-07     2                0                100
2017-05-07     1                0                107
2017-05-08     1                0                100
2017-05-08     0                1                107
2017-05-15     2                0                100 
2017-05-15     1                0                104 
2017-05-09     0                1                100
2017-05-10     0                3                100
2017-05-20     0                1                100
2017-05-21     0                1                100
2017-05-21     0                1                104
2017-06-01     1                0                104
2017-06-03     1                0                104
2017-06-17     1                0                104
2017-06-10     0                2                104
2017-06-20     0                1                104
```

**What I have tried**:

I have no idea to take all dates to a new table(result) as above. I tried to find no_admission by:

```
SELECT admission as date, count(name) as no_admission, unit FROMtbl_user GROUP BY admission
```

And tried to find the no_discharge by:

```
SELECT discharge as date, count(name) as no_discharge, unit FROMtbl_user GROUP BY discharge
```

But still am unable to find my result as expected..

Please help me to find the expected result..

Comment: I personally would just run two queries to get the count of each grouped by date and add those to a single array indexed by the date. IMO, any other options would quickly become easily confusing/unreadable and harder to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricky part here is that you have two dates on the same line that sometimes need to be counted; sometimes not and really need to be on two different lines for each date.  One way to achieve this is to unpivot the dates using two select statements and then sum.

```
SELECT d.mdate, sum(d.no_Admission) as No_Admission, sum(d.no_Discharge) as no_Discharge, d.unit
FROM (SELECT admission as mdate, 1 as No_Admission, 0 as No_Discharge, unit
      FROM tbl_user
      UNION ALL

      SELECT discharge as mdate, 0 as No_Admission, 1 as No_Discharge, unit
      FROM tbl_user) d
GROUP BY d.mdate, d.unit
```

Another way ***may*** be to create a distinct list of dates then left join in the appropriate records based on date.  The below is untested and I'm unsure if the records would have the counts artificially inflated due to the multiple joins to tlb_user.  I think not; but not positive.

```
SELECT mdate
     , count(A.Admission) as No_Admission
     , count(D.Discharge) as No_Discharge
     , coalesce(A.Unit, D.Unit) as unit
FROM (SELECT admission as mdate FROM tbl_user
      UNION 
      SELECT discharge as mdate FROM tbl_user) d
LEFT JOIN tbl_user A
 on d.mDate = A.admission
LEFT JOIN tbl_user D
 on d.mdate = D.Discharge
 and A.Unit = D.Unit
GROUP BY mdate, coalsece(A.Unit, D.Unit)
```

Comment: First query you provided is working..Second query gives` FUNCTION db_name.coalsece does not exist`  exception